# To get time zone ID of the given GMT time +0530

Tags: java, time, java-8, timezone, timezone-offset

How to get the time zone id e.g "Asia/Calcutta"? When I pass the value GMT+0530 to a method, it should return the Timezone id, e.g "Asia/Calcutta".

```
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0530"); // LINE B
    System.out.println(timeZone.getID());
```

Comment: What if there are 10 timezones with that offset? Which one should you return then? Why do you use an offset if your goal is to have a timezone? Why not use a timezone instead?

Comment: This has been asked a couple of time, and the general answer has been that it is not possible. Please use your search engine to find the details.

Comment: See if this helps.[link](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-display-list-of-timezone-with-gmt/)

Comment: @Nishant Since the OP marks that s/he is using Java 8, it is of course more helpful to provide [the Java 8 version: link](http://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-display-all-zoneid-and-its-utc-offset/).